# Voucher email don't send automatically

Tags: opencart

When user buys voucher, they get the confirmation purchase email but the recipient don't get the email with the voucher code. I have to log in the Admin and click the send email button to send the voucher code manually to the recipient. So the mail protocol is working fine, it's just that the code doesn't seem to call the send function after purchase. How come?

Answer (score 0):

I the admin panel system settings "Option" tab there is a setting which reads:

***Complete Order Status:***
Set the order status the customers order must reach before they are allowed to access their downloadable products and gift vouchers.

Make sure the customer's order is set to match this setting and the voucher should be sent.  Otherwise, the voucher will be sent anytime the order matches the ***Complete Order Status*** setting.

Comment: Nope even if the order status of the voucher is the same as in the settings. The voucher email isn't sent. Both settings and order are set to "completed" and the voucher's enabled but no email sent.

Comment: in that case you'll need to dig in to the code and do some debugging.  if you have any vqmods installed i'd recommend disabling them temporarily and see if the problem persists.  but as it stands if your system is sending emails ok then it should be working as long as the statuses are in agreeance. you might also consider upvoting my answer since it is both correct and helpful - notwithstanding the deeper problems in your installation.